# jQuery Ajax returning undefined from controller action method

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, asp.net-core

In my ASP.NET Core 3.1 application, I am implementing cascading DropDown functionality using jQuery. Value change of the first DropDown (Region) should populate the second DropDown, Locations. When changing the value of ddlRegion, the jQuery is correctly hitting the Controller method and also returning the results in the json list but the results in the second DropDown are getting populated as 'undefined'.

[DropDown HTML]

```
   <table style="margin-left:2%;margin-top:2%">
        <tr style="width:200px">
            <td style="width:100px">Region</td>
            <td style="width:300px">
                @Html.DropDownList("DDLRegion", new List<SelectListItem>
        {
           new SelectListItem{ Text="-- Select --", Value = "0" },
           new SelectListItem{ Text="North", Value = "1" },
           new SelectListItem{ Text="South", Value = "2" },
           new SelectListItem{ Text="All", Value = "3" }
        }, new { @id = "DDLRegion" })

            </td>
            <td style="width:100px">Location</td>
            <td style="width:300px">
                @Html.DropDownList("DDLLocation", new List<SelectListItem>
                {
                   new SelectListItem{ Text="-- Select --", Value = "0" },
                   }, new { @id = "DDLLocation" })
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

[jQuery Code]

$(document).ready(function () {
$("#DDLRegion").change(function () {

```
        $("#DDLLocation").empty();
            $.ajax({

                type: 'GET',

                url: '/GetLocations/1',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { id: $("#DDLRegion").val() },

                success: function (locationsList) {

                    $.each(locationsList, function (i,location) {

                        $('#DDLLocation').append('<option value="'
                            + location.Value + '">' +
                            location.Text + '</option>');
                    });
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve locations');
                }
            });
            return false;
        })
});
```

[Controller Code]

```
   [Route("~/GetLocations/{id}")]
    public JsonResult GetLocations(string id)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> locations =
                    new List<SelectListItem>();

        int counter = 0;
        string line;

        locations.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = "Select",
            Value = "0"
        });

        switch (id)
        {
            case "1":
                // Read the file and display it line by line.  
                System.IO.StreamReader file =
                    new System.IO.StreamReader(@"North_Locations.txt");
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    locations.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = line, Value = counter.ToString() });
                    counter++;
                }

                file.Close();
                counter = 0;
                line = "";

                break;
            case "2":

                // Read the file and display it line by line.  
                System.IO.StreamReader file2 =
                    new System.IO.StreamReader(@"South_Locations.txt");
                while ((line = file2.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    locations.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = line, Value = counter.ToString() });
                    counter++;
                }

                file2.Close();
                counter = 0;
                line = "";
                break;
         }

        return Json(new SelectList(locations,
                        "Value", "Text"));
    }
}
```

In jQuery code, the 'location' is coming as undefined. If the controller returns 80 items then the location dropdown gets filled with 80 'undefined'.

Comment: It seems the result rows don't have Text property. You need to check return json.

Comment: @Eanthmue I checked the return locations. It has the Text.

Comment: @freedomn-m I referred to the code here: https://geeksarray.com/blog/cascading-dropdownlist-example-using-jsonresult-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: I wasn't sure the format of jsonifying a SelectList so created a .net fiddle - it serialises as a simple array of objects - so using SelectListItem/SelectList seems overkill to me, but I guess it already has the properties you need.

Comment: Probably off topic: you're url should be `url: '/GetLocations/1',` not `url: '/GetLocations,` as you're passing the id as data, so it will always be `1` regardless of the region.

Comment: @freedomn-m Controller is forming correct json but when it iterates through locations in jquery, there it has issues.

Comment: I suspect the serializer use camelCase. Try `append('<option value="' + location.value + '">' + location.text + '</option>');`

Comment: @freedomn-m Tried:   url: '@Url.Action("GetLocations")',  Same result

Comment: Please capture the request and check the actual response data in browser developer tool Network tab.

Comment: @vernou It worked. It was the camel case issue. Please post as Answer and I will mark it.

Comment: "*it has the `Text`*" ... "*it works with `text`"* - these are not the same - this is why we ask to see the *actual* value, not just take your word for it.

Comment: I edited @Izzy answer to add this information. Can you accept him answer?

Comment: Thanks all for the quick response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the serializer use camelCase. When your explore the result in ajax success, the first letter need be minuscule.

Also you can simplify your approach and return `SelectListItem` in your response. So you action will look something like:

```
public IActionResult GetLocations(string id)
{
    //you will change the below to match your code
    var locations = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
         new SelectListItem("First Value", "1"),
         new SelectListItem("Second Value", "2"),
         new SelectListItem("Third Value", "3"),
    };

    return Json(locations);
}
```

I've made use of `getJSON` as:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var url = '@Url.Action("GetLocations", "Home")';
    var location = $('#DDLLocation');

    $("#DDLRegion").change(function() {
        var id = $(this).val();
        $.getJSON(url, { id: id }, function(response) {
                location.empty();
                $.each(response,
                    function(index, item) {
                        location.append($('<option></option>').text(item.text).val(item.value));
                    });
            });
    });
});
```